# What are the feathers on Rei's neck?

Tags: vividred-operation

As of episode 7, we know the following:

- Rei is somehow connected to the Alones that are attacking the city.
- The (unnamed) black bird is able to inflict extreme pain on Rei through those feathers.
- Every time Rei fires an arrow at an Alone, she consumes one feather.

[image]

Is there anything else that has been revealed? Do these feathers symbolize anything?

Comment: [Note that the appropriateness of such questions has been covered on this meta post.](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/457/should-questions-that-are-unanswerable-until-later-unaired-episodes-chapters-b)

Answer (score 4):

As of Episode 7, it's been revealed that it indicates how many Empowering Arrows she can fire and that she only has twelve of these arrows available.